# Alternative for bash's 'read -t' in POSIX shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm currently working on a college project where I have to do several shell script files. In one of them, I have to create a file called `taunt.sh` that uses the command `cowsay` to print some messages depending on some actions:

1. If no message is received after 10 seconds then the `taunt.sh` script should issue a funny message and finish/exit.
2. If it receives the `SIGHUP` signal, then it should issue a special message and exit.
3. If it receives a `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, then it should issue a taunt and terminate/exit.

The thing is, I need to use `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/bash`.

I know in `bash` we can use `read -t 10 input` to wait for 10 seconds while an input is received, and we could exit of the waiting process after receiving some input.

But this is not an option in `sh`.

So, is there a way to implement some similar functionality in `sh`?

I tried this

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter your input:"
sleep 10 &
read input
kill $! 2>/dev/null

if [ -z "$input" ]; then
  echo "No input provided"
else
  echo "You entered: $input"
fi
```

But it never got out after 10 seconds, only if I typed something.

I'm pretty new to `sh` and still takes me a while to understand some things. So I hope somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a [`POSIX`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/) version of the bash's `read -t 10`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

timeout=10
mystty="$(stty -g)"
trap 'stty "$mystty"' EXIT   
stty -icanon min 0 time $((timeout*10))

echo "Enter your input "
read input

if [ -z "$input" ]; then
  echo "No input provided"
else
  echo "You entered: $input"
fi
```

---

- `mystty="$(stty -g)"` save `stty` settings in a variable
- `trap 'stty "$mystty"' EXIT`: This line set a trap for the `EXIT`¹ signal. In this case, when the script exits, it will restores those settings in any cases (<kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> or any exit cases) for the following terminal modifications :
- `stty -icanon min 0 time 100`: This line modifies the terminal settings using the `stty` command. The `-icanon` flag disables canonical mode, which means that input is processed immediately, without waiting for a newline character. The `min 0` setting means that the terminal will not wait for any characters to be typed before returning input. The `time 100` set a timeout of 100 deciseconds (10 seconds) to read input. In this mode, if no input is received within the specified timeout, the read operation will return immediately.

---

¹ [POSIX `trap exit`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Could you please explain me what do the `trap` and `stty` commands do in your code?

Comment: For the record, I wasn't sure whether the `EXIT` keyword for `trap` is supported in POSIX; but [it is.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap)